# Undefined variable: factory Laravel 8 Livewire

Tags: php, database, virtualbox, shopping-cart, laravel-livewire

I am new to Laravel/Livewire/Jetstream and I am trying to create a shopping cart project following this [tutorial] (https://lightit.io/blog/laravel-livewire-shopping-cart-demo/). I am using Laravel 8/ OS Ubuntu in virtual box.
I get an exception error  Undefined variable: factory when I tried to run this command `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

error content

```
Seeding: Database\Seeders\ProductSeeder

   ErrorException 

  Undefined variable: factory

  at database/factories/ProductFactory.php:7
      3▕ /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
      4▕ use App\Models\Product;
      5▕ use Faker\Generator as Faker;
      6▕ 
  ➜   7▕ $factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
      8▕     return [
      9▕         'name' => $faker->word,
     10▕         'description' => $faker->text(180),
     11▕         'price' => $faker->numberBetween(50, 100)

  1   database/factories/ProductFactory.php:7
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError()

      +2 vendor frames 
  4   [internal]:0
      Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass()
```

composer.json file

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
```

database/migrations/xxxx_xx_xx_xxxxxx_create_products_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->float('price');
            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

database/factories/ProductFactory.php

```
    <?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
use App\Models\Product;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->word,
        'description' => $faker->text(180),
        'price' => $faker->numberBetween(50, 100)
    ];
});
```

database/seeders/ProductSeeder.php

```
    <?php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ProductSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Product::factory()->count(50)->create();
    }
}
```

database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php

```
    <?php

use Database\Seeders\ProductSeeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
'{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(ProductSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to understand what I did wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `ProductFactory::class` seems to following Laravel 7 conventions. Laravel 8 model factories feature has been totally rewritten to support classes and is not compatible with Laravel 7.x style factories.

Here's what you can do:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Product::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'description' => $this->faker->realText(180),
            'price' => $this->faker->numberBetween(50, 100)
        ];
    }
}
```

Also, you will need to update your `Product Model` as well:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. My Product model was already updated.